# how to create virtual playback devices in windows server 2016/2019

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-server, audio-streaming

I tried to install many drivers like VB cable audio cable
https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/usage.htm
https://vb-audio.com/Cable/

but none of them worked for me
only when I connect to the server am able to see
the remote audio in the "playback" device tab soon I disconnect it'll get removed
[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhZLH.png)

**so is there any way to create a virtual or fake device in the windows server
to stream audio**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you need to install Virtual Audio Cable on a server?

Comment: it's a project which streams and records audio from a different servers